# Best way of including commonjs modules in a project using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, commonjs, umd

I using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) to manage the javascript files in my project. However, there are some external libraries I want to use that do not adhere to the [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) format. A library I want to include is [barba.js](https://github.com/luruke/barba.js). How would this be done using the [package loading feature](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages) of requirejs? Ideally I want to include a commonjs module without running a conversion tool.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something big here, barba.js does adhere to the AMD format, the first lines of the code try using different solutions such as exports and define. This means it should work just fine with requireJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barba doesn't use the CommonJS module format.

Barba uses the [**UMD (Universal Module Definition)**](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/) module format. This means that it is compatible with **both** the AMD module loading (as used by RequireJS) and CommonJS module loading (as used by Node.js).

So, that means you can just include Barba - or any other module in UMD format - with RequireJS the same way you include an AMD module:

```
define([
  "barba/barba"
], function(Barba) {
  Barba.Pjax.start(); // You can use Barba here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From requireJS doc.

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    //Put traditional CommonJS module content here
});
```

This should make everything alright for you. I'm really not sure if it's needed though.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this option but I'd prefer not to manually modify each file if possible..

Comment: As I hinted tough, I don't think you should even need to do it... Looking at the barba.js source code, I think it is made for it to work with requireJS.